# Windbreak on urban balcony

Tags: containers, wind-damage, field-windbreak

I'm looking for a wind break solution for my balcony. It's a rented property (British/EU) and I am not allowed to drill into external wall. It is a top-floor, south-facing balcony and is pretty much fully exposed. On a gusty day wind can be 30+mph and rose is mostly between S-W. I'd like to try and grow food in containers so I need something that doesn't cut through too much light into the balcony and flat.

[image]
Options I have considered are:

- Awnings - Unfortunately I can't drill into the wall so this does not seem an option.
- Trellis -  Maybe on both sides, or on both corners? The balcony is not big, I wonder how tall that can be so they don't tip over in high winds.
- Windscreen - I personally am not a fan of plasticky screens. Maybe bamboo could be an option, I'd like to let the light fall into the balcony as much as possible. If I choose bamboo ones it'll be quite sparse. Will it still be effective in breaking the wind?

Which one would you recommend, trellis or windscreen? If with trellis, any climbing plants (other than ivy) I can consider? Do I have any other options?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your need for light and blocking of the wind, I think you'd be best off with polycarbonate sheets, like [these in the UK](https://www.polycarbonatesheets.co.uk/contents/en-uk/d79.html). They're very cost-effective, reusable, and can be drilled through for attaching to the balcony railing (maybe with zip-ties or coated wire). As you can see from the website, you can get these cut to the exact height you'd need to cover the entire balcony from floor to top of railing or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Glass with clamps; it will probably cost 100 X the cost of the food you grow. Plastic film such as used in greenhouses will need replacement each year and seems to be cloudy blocking much light. I have 1/4 in. plate glass in my shed roof for years , works great, survived bad hail storms, falling trees, etc.